# Prove that in an obtuse triangle the orthocentre is the excenter of the orthic triangle

Tags: geometry

Consider an obtuse angled $\Delta ABC$ with altitudes $AD, BE, CF$ concurrent at $H$. Consider the orthic triangle $\Delta FED$. Extend $ED$ to $D'$ and $EF$ to $F'$. Prove that $\angle FDH = \angle HDD'$ and $\angle DFH = \angle HFF'$. In other words prove that $H$ is the excenter of $\Delta FED$.

I tackled $\angle FDH = \angle HDD'$ first. 
I tried reducing the proof to a simpler statement:

Since $\angle D'DH = \angle ADE$, and $\angle FDH = 90 - \angle FDB$, it is sufficient to prove that $\angle ADE + \angle FDB = 90$

Now,  the proof hinges on the conjecture that in an orthic triangle of an obtuse triangle, the point with the obtuse angle is the incenter of the orthic triangle. I was unable to prove this conjecture. Is there a proof for this conjecture (or is it incorrect altogether?), or is there an alternative proof to the whole problem?

Comment: What are $D'$ and $F'$?

Comment: "Extend $ED$ to $D'$ and $EF$ to $F'$"

Comment: That's why I asked. Extend to where?

Comment: To wherever you like :P. It doesn't matter. Its just for naming the angles.

Comment: I see  $D'$ and $F'$ aren't particularly significant. This is a basic result about orthocenter (it also applies for acute triangles though $H$ would correspond to the incenter of $FED$). Just use the fact that HDEA and AFDC are cyclic.

Comment: I think there's some mistake in your labelling: surely you mean $BFHD$ is cyclic.

Comment: I didn't say otherwise. There are several cyclic quadrilaterals there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**

- Consider angles inscribed in circumcircles of the following quadrilaterals: $BDHF$, $ADBE$ and $BFCE$.

I hope this helps ;-)